# How to check iOS sandbox container files locations?

Tags: ios, xcode

I've downloaded the sandbox of my APP from a connected test device using Xcode. After opening it using "finder", I see the following folders as expected.

```
Documents
Library 
StoreKit
tmp
```

But when I look into the above directories I can find none of the files that are used by the APP. For example, the APP uses over 40 jpg files, why are they not being shown inside the downloaded sandbox package at all?

Comment: Are the jpg files bundled with the app?  If so they aren't part of the sandbox, they're part of the application.

Comment: This could be the reason ...  I haven't explicitly put the jpg files into the sandbox. So the jpg files would never be shown in the sandbox unless they have been put into it explicitly?

Comment: Yes, like I said, if they were distributed as part of the app they're in its bundle, not the sandbox.  The app is readonly; the sandbox is read/write.

Comment: How do you explicitly put files into an iOS sandbox?

Comment: I think you're looking for something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44434428/swift-3-copy-folder-w-contents-from-main-bundle-to-documents-directory

Comment: Thanks for the link. If you have something similar in objective-c, it would also be very useful.

Answer (score 0):

As Philip Mills has suggested, it is normal not to have the jpg files in the sandbox folders as they are bundled in the app.

Files need to be explicitly put in the sandbox folders in order to be there.